# SQL Product Group Size & Colors Together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have following 3 tables, which I want to use to group 2 rows together to make it as single row, because they belong to one product.

```
Order
--------
order_id

Order_product
-------------
order_id
order_product_id

order_product_attribute
------------------------------
orders_products_attributes_id
order_id
product_id
products_options
options_id  

=== Data ===
|1|2|7|Size      |1|270
|2|2|7|Colour(s) |3|99202
|3|2|8|Size      |1|270
|4|2|8|Colour(s) |3|47768
```

My desire result needs to be following:

```
order_id, product_id, size_options_id (option_id for size), colour_options_id (option_id for color)
```

size_options_id is optional, which means it might not even exist for some products.

I'm not sure what join I need to use to get this result in one go, rather then doing it from PHP checks.

Comment: Don't store data like that! Use different columns/tables, not attributes.

Comment: I think that you should provide exact structure and data of all your tables. Why provided data has 6 column?

Comment: size color id is just options_id value for size and color option id is options_id again for colors.. its stored in 2 rows, we need in single row.. which is not stored in database.

Comment: When posting database/sql related question it's really useful to provide the exact table definitions and sample data for all tables used. Ideally a SQL Fiddle link would be provided too. You did include some of the data and that's commendable, but please take the time and provide _all_ relevant details. At 2k+ rep and with ~150 questions asked this should come naturally.

Comment: @jpw Thanks for suggestion. I didn't had in mind about sql fiddle, but next time I will definitely will be adding sql fiddle, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your tables are as follows:

```
create table order (order_id int);
insert into order values(2);

create table order_product (order_id int, order_product_id int);
insert into order_product values (2,7);
insert into order_product values (2,8);

create table order_product_attribute (orders_products_attributes_id int, order_id int, product_id int, products_options int, options_id int);
insert into order_product_attribute values (1, 2, 7, 1, 270);
insert into order_product_attribute values (2, 2, 7, 3, 99202);
insert into order_product_attribute values (3, 2, 8, 1, 270);
insert into order_product_attribute values (4, 2, 8, 3, 47768);

desired output:

2  7  270 99202
2  8  270 47768
```

You should use two left joins. It should be something like:

```
select 
   o.order_id, 
   op.product_id, 
   opas.options_id as size_options_id, 
   opac.options_id as colour_options_id 
from my_order o
join order_product op on op.order_id=o.order_id
left join order_product_attribute opas 
   on opas.order_id=o.order_id 
   and opas.product_id=op.product_id
   and opas.product_options=1
left join order_product_attribute opac 
   on opac.order_id=o.order_id 
   and opac.product_id=op.product_id
   and opac.product_options=3
```

First left join is joining only with these rows which contain sizes.
Second left join is joining with rows containing colors.

You can see it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/550d73/3)

Comment: It's giving me null value for sizes and colors

Comment: @Basit What data do you have in `product_options` column?  Numbers (1, 3) or names (Colour, Size)?